# Many to Many Eloquent - Same Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

Sorry as I am a relative Laravel beginner.

I have a model called PACS. Each PACS can be related to many other PACS. The relationship from one to another also has a direction, push or pull.

My PACS model has a many to many relationship defined as

```
public function pacsRelation() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\PACS', 'pacs_has_pacs', 'pacsId', 'hasPacsId')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('transferRelation');
    }
```

my pivot table is

```
Schema::create('pacs_has_pacs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('pacsId')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('hasPacsId')->unsigned();
            $table->enum('transferRelation', ['push', 'pull']);

            $table->foreign('pacsId')->references('pacsId')->on('pacs');
            $table->foreign('hasPacsId')->references('pacsId')->on('pacs');
        });
```

my PACS model table is

```
Schema::create('pacs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('pacsId');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('fax')->nullable();
            $table->string('edi')->nullable();
            $table->string('contact');
        });
```

I am having troubles as I am executing the following code and am having no rows appear in my pivot table and no errors.

```
public function handle()
    {

        $this->error("The relationship is defined push or pull by how the receiving party is able to retreive images from the sending party.");

        $valid = false;

        while (!$valid) {

            $receiving = $this->ask('Receiving PACS name');

            try {
                $pacs = PACS::where('name', '=', $receiving)->firstOrFail();
            } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
                $this->error('This PACS does not exist');
                continue;
            }

            $valid = true;

        }

        $this->info($pacs);

        $valid = false;

        while (!$valid) {

            $sending = $this->ask('Sending PACS name');

            try {
                $sendingPacs = PACS::where('name', '=', $sending)->firstOrFail();
            } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
                $this->error('This PACS does not exist');
                continue;
            }

            $valid = true;

        }

        $this->info($sendingPacs);

        $relation = $this->choice('Push or Pull relation?', ['push', 'pull']);

        $pacs->pacsRelation()->save($sendingPacs, ['transferRelation'=>$relation]);

        $this->info('Relationship successfully defined.');

    }
```

Is there something obvious I am missing or have I gone about this the wrong way?

Comment: look into `attach()` ... https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem after many hours of looking came down to Laravel not recognising the primary key of my table.

I had to define

```
protected $primaryKey = 'pacsId';
```

on my PACS model and I was away.